# Upper Riemann Integral is greater than or equal to lower Riemann Integral

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I need to prove that
$$ \underline{\int_{a}^{b}} f dx \le \overline{\int_{a}^{b}} f dx$$
which is same as showing
$$\sup_P L(f;P) \le \inf_P U(f;P)$$

Where $U(f;P)$ , $L(f;P)$ are Upper and Lower Riemann Sums, $P$ is Partition and $f$ is a function. I proceed as below
$$L(f;P) \le  U(f;P)  \ \forall P$$
$$\sup_P L(f;P) \le  U(f;P)  \ \forall P$$
$$\sup_P L(f;P) \le \inf_P U(f;P)$$
Is this correct reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. The step
$$L(f;P) \le  U(f;P)  \ \forall P \Rightarrow \sup_P L(f;P) \le  U(f;P)  \ \forall P$$
is not justified. Theoretically it could be possible that $L(f;P') >  U(f;P)$ for distinct partitions $P, P'$. But fortunately we have
$$L(f;P') \le  U(f;P)  \ \forall P', P \tag{1}$$
which leads to a correct argument.

To prove $(1)$, observe that if $Q$ refines $P$, then
$$L(f;P) \le L(f;Q) \quad, \quad U(f;Q) \le U(f;P) .$$

For any two $P',P$ we can choose a common refinement $Q$ and get
$$L(f;P') \le L(f;Q) \le U(f;Q) \le U(f;P) .$$

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Isn't $P$ and $P'$ distinct partition?Secondly, the Lower Riemann sum is always less than the area under the curve which is lower than Upper Riemann Sum. So if we take supremum over lower Riemann sum it will always be less than the area under the curve which will be less than Upper Riemann sum. Why supremum step is not justified.

Comment: @MathStarter What exactly do you mean by "area under the curve"?  $f$ is not necessarily integrable, so you are trying to insert this nonexistent quantity called "area under the curve" in the middle.

Comment: Your inequality is correct for any (bounded) $f$, but an *area under the curve* only exists for integrable $f$. Without knowing that $(1)$ is true you cannot argue that $L(f;P) \le  U(f;P)  \ \forall P \Rightarrow \sup_P L(f;P) \le  U(f;P)  \ \forall P$. Thus without proving $(1)$ your proof has a serious gap. If you want, I can add a proof of $(1)$. As an example for the failure ofy our argument take this: Let $x_n = y_n = n$. Then $x_n \le y_n \forall n$, but $\sup_n x_n = \infty > y_n \forall n$.